# Разработка и отладка для arm-linux из Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, arm

может быть кто то сталкивался с подобным ?
Есть эмулятор Raspberry Pi emulation for Windows
https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/
Линукс запускается там
Есть реальная железяка на вот таком проце
https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/AT91RM9200
Там также стоит линукс на ней
Есть ли возможность подружить студию так что бы можно было собирать бинарники для целевой платформы и отлаживать их на удаленной целевой платформе ?